# Accessing public property of a @Lazy initialized @Bean with @PropertySource

Tags: java, spring, lazy-loading

Spring 4.3.12

I'm using @Configuration classes to lazy initialize a bean

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {
    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public Config config(){
        propertySourceInjector().injectToEnvironment();
        return new Config();
    }

    @Bean
    public PropertySourceInjector propertySourceInjector(){
        return new PropertySourceInjector ();
    }
}
```

Config class:

```
public class Config{
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Value("${customConfigValue}")
    public Integer configValue;

    public Integer getConfigValue() {
        return configValue;
    }
}
```

PropertySourceInjector class:

```
public class PropertySourceInjector {
    public void injectToEnvironment(){
         //reads DB and adds a property source to Spring Enviroment's property sources
    }
}
```

When I access Config.getValue() method, injection occurs properly. The PropertySource is added and @Value assigns the correct value to field `configValue`.

```
@Autowired @Lazy 
Config config;

System.out.println(Config.getConfigValue());  //works!!
```

When I access Config.value public field, injection never occurs. The bean is not initialized.

```
@Autowired @Lazy 
Config config;

System.out.println(Config.configValue)  //Fails. Prints null
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Config.configValue` is a direct access of a field.
The Lazy proxy does nothing for direct access, so there is nothing to trigger bean load.

Make `configValue` a private field and use a getter.